# django paypal notify_url not configured correctly or working

Tags: django, python-2.7, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I did a pip install for django paypal. The button renders and the payment goes through. The return url works too but the notify_url part is not working. So I cannot update my database that a sale has gone through.

I don't get any errors either so I am stumped. If someone can help Id really appreciate it. Thanks

> Edit: I added `from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful` to the top of my views page. and changed the name of my notify_url to show_me_the_money (Not sure if that matters) I got it from a blog called http://djangodersleri.blogspot.ie/2013/11/paypal-ipn-with-django.html. But the good thing is now at least I seem to be getting my transactions recorded in the table paypal_ipn. But that's all! So still dont know if the show_me_the_money view is being executed.

Here is what I have..

Settings...

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
        'paypal.standard.ipn',
)
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "my_sandbox_test_email_is_here@gmail.com"
PAYPAL_TEST = True
```

URLS...

```
(r'^show_me_the_money /', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
```

Views...

```
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received 
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful

def show_me_the_money (sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        doc_id=ipn_obj.item_number1 # :document_id,
        us_id=ipn_obj.item_number2 #user.id,
        obj_doc=Document.objects.get(id=doc_id)
        my_user = User.objects.get(id=us_id)
        obj_doc.users.add(my_user)
        obj_doc.save()


    try:
        ipn_obj.verify(item_check_callable)
    except:
        import sys, traceback
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)           

    valid_ipn_received.connect(paid)

@csrf_exempt
def myvideos(request):


    try:
        my_vids=Document.objects.filter(users=request.user.id)#request.user.id
    except: 
        return render_to_response(
        'myvideos.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )

       #my_vids= Document.objects.filter(users=request.user.id)       
    return render_to_response(
        'myvideos.html',
        {'my_vids': my_vids},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )


def video(request, document_id):

    document = Document.objects.get(id=document_id)

    if request.user.id:
        d1 =datetime.datetime.now()
        t=d1.strftime('%y%m%d%h%m%s')
        pp_price = str(document.price)
        # What you want the button to do.
        paypal_dict = {
            "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
            "amount": pp_price + ".00",
            "item_number1":document_id,
            "item_number2":request.user.id,
            "item_name": document.name,
            "invoice": document.name+t,
            "notify_url": "http://wackosmackosite.com/"+ reverse('paypal-ipn'),
            "return_url": "http://wackosmackosite.com/myvideos/",
            "cancel_return": "http://wackosmackosite.com/video/"+document_id+"/",
        }
        form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)

        context = {"form": form, "document":document }
        return render(request, "video.html", context)
    else:
        return render_to_response('video.html',{'document': document},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is the The urls from paypal.standard.ipn

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from paypal.standard.ipn import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ipn, name="paypal-ipn"),
]
```

Comment: Could be an issue with your notify_url and return_url not being https.

Comment: Is it a requirement to have a SSL? My return url is working fine also.

Comment: I'm still absolutely stumped by this. I even ran a successful ipn simulator test from my paypal sandbox. but it is still not calling my show_me_the_money view. Anyone ? please I beg :)

Comment: So is your notify_url still not working? Also, to troubleshoot the show_me_the_money function, it would help to see the urls in `paypal.standard.ipn.urls`. BTW, the one url you do show has a typo (there's an extra space before the leading slash): `(r'^show_me_the_money/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),`

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. I Added urls from paypal.standard.ipn above. There was no space in the urls before the leading slash in my real code by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off  @mcastle Thank you so much for your help. But I just couldn't figure out the Django signals.

Ok so what I had to do in the end is go to the paypal.standard.ipn.views file and import my app and call the show_me_the_money view from there at the very bottom of the view just before it returns the http response.

So the notify url in the paypal dict like this...

```
"notify_url": "http://wackosmackosite.com/show_me_the_money/",
```

And the url in my urls file is like this..

```
 url(r'^show_me_the_money/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
```

I was able to extract the info I needed to update my database from the arguments passed to show_me_the_money. like this...

```
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender

    payStatus=ipn_obj.POST.get('payment_status','')

    if payStatus=='Completed':
        ....
```

Then in the paypal ipn view 
at the top...

```
from myApp.views import show_me_the_money
```

At the bottom...

```
s_m_t_m=show_me_the_money(request, item_check_callable=None)
return HttpResponse("OKAY")
```

I found this whole set-up very confusing and think the documentaion for me just leaves lots of important stuff out. Anyway This is working perfect now and I just got off the phone with pay pal and they are happy it is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Review Django's documentation on [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions). `show_me_the_money` looks like it needs to be connected to a signal.

Comment: Do you mean I should add that as well as having this one?... (r'^show_me_the_money /', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),

Comment: Correct. Or move the logic in `show_me_the_money` to a view that's already linked to an existing url. Basically, you need to call `show_me_the_money` either by a url or by another function.

Comment: I added that url like you said and it still does not get to the show_me_the_money function. I just don't get what reverse('paypal-ipn' is all about.

Comment: Did you enter that url in your browser? And if so, were there any errors?

Comment: I get a blank screen. Sorry I did get an error : WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'payment_status'